# Excel index match with two different sheets gives me #VALUE error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do an `index` `match` on two tables from two different sheets.

I have tried using a + sign to add the two different index match formulas
I have tried to add the index and match functions with commas

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Building!$H$4:$H$3490,MATCH($I5,Building!$A$4:$A$3490,0)),0)
```

works

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AltCapID!$H$2:$H$608,MATCH($A5,AltCapID!$A$2:$A$608,0)),0)
```

works

what I want is if the first condition doesn't exist to execute the second formula

Current formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Building!$H$4:$H$3490,MATCH($I6,Building!$A$4:$A$3490,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX(AltCapID!$H$2:$H$608,MATCH($A6,AltCapID!$A$2:$A$608,0)),0)
```

`I6` matches the value in `Building!$A$4:$A$3490` so I am expecting the results from `Building!$H$4:$H$3490` instead I am getting an `#VALUE` error

Comment: What is the result of the two formulas that work?

Answer (score 0):

After editing your question, what you are looking is the following formula:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Building!$H$4:$H$3490,MATCH($I5,Building!$A$4:$A$3490,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(AltCapID!$H$2:$H$608,MATCH($A5,AltCapID!$A$2:$A$608,0)),0))
```

Comment: I have set this up incorrectly, I shouldn't be using the + sign, I don't want to sum the two formulas. What I want is if the first formula is 0 to execute the second formula

Answer (score 0):

After reading my answer again, I realized all I needed was an if statement. So I added

=IF(A5="",IFERROR(INDEX(Building!$H$4:$H$3490,MATCH($A5,AltCapID!$A$2:$A$608,0)),0)),IFERROR(INDEX(AltCapID!$H$2:$H$608,MATCH($A5,AltCapID!$A$2:$A$608,0)),0))

In my table Column A is empty if that cell is to be used